# What happened to HttpConfiguration.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using the new WebTools 2012.2, and the help files says to add config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing to your Global.asax.

However, this method doesnt exist on HttpConfiguration.

Answer (score 12):

The `EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing` extension is part of the Tracing package. Do you have the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing` package installed?

Also make sure to have the `using System.Web.Http;` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Documentation: [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api)

To install use:

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

After that check the following in your project:

1. Add dll-file \packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.Tracing.dll to your project.
2. Add the following to WebApiConfig.cs
   using System.Web.Http;
   using System.Web.Http.Tracing;

And

//tracing
config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

Answer (score 0):

Because it is an extension method, you need a using statement where the extension method is declared.  So in your Global.asax.cs or whereever you want to call EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing(), you need to add this at the top:

```
 using System.Web.Http;
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it trace by default to the Output window for projects created using WebAPI template, if you have Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2? EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing does the same.